# Rewriting 3 commands into one command or script that can be run on cron

Tags: ruby, shell

Im currently using 3 different commands to achieve my goal of downloading a zip, extracting it, converting the txt file to utf8 and then converting the csv to json!

First I have:

```
wget https://www.example.com/example.zip -O temp.zip; unzip -o temp.zip; rm temp.zip
```

Which is good, but the problem to start with is how do I rename the file that is extracted so its the same every time for the next processes as it can be a different name within the zip every day? Next I run this script depending on the filename that converts the ISO to utf8:

```
sh dir_iconv.sh example1.txt ISO8859-1 UTF-8
```

Which is this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ICONVBIN='/usr/bin/iconv' # path to iconv binary

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
echo "$0 dir from_charset to_charset"
exit
fi

for f in $1/*
do
if test -f $f
then
    echo -e "\nConverting $f"
    /bin/mv $f $f.old
    $ICONVBIN -f $2 -t $3 $f.old > $f
    rm -f $f.old
else
    echo -e "\nSkipping $f - not a regular file";
fi
done
```

And then finally I run a ruby script csv2json - https://github.com/darwin/csv2json - that is called as follows (pipe delimited) to give me a json output:

```
csv2json -s '|' example1.txt > example1.json
```

Is there a simple way to roll this into one command or script that can be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe all your commands one after another and, if necessary, throw them in a shell script file.

```
wget -qO- https://www.example.com/example.zip | unzip | iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8 | csv2json > example.json
```